# yum-config-manager --add-repo https://my-server/yum-proxy/ generates strange name

Tags: yum

I have created a yum proxy in nexus using this guide:
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/yum-repositories#YumRepositories-ProxyingYumRepositories

No I would like to add the proxy to yum. I do:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://my-server/yum-proxy/
```

which outputs:

```
[my-server_yum-proxy_]
name=added from: https://my-server/yum-proxy/
baseurl=https://my-server/yum-proxy/
enabled=1
```

but that name looks rather strange. Is it not possible to specify the name to the command when adding the repo?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it seems like `yum-config-manager` does not have an option to specify the name. If the name bothers you, you can generate the repository manually like this:

```
echo "[my-proxy]
name=my-proxy
baseurl=https://my-server/yum-proxy/
enabled=1" | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/my-proxy.repo
```